# Why does my CREATE TABLE statement raise an ORA-00905: missing keyword error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
CustId varchar(10) not null, 
custname varchar(15), 
Ic varchar(15),
AttributeName varchar(10), 
Birthdate varchar(10), 
Birthstate varchar(10), 
Race varchar(10), 
Gender varchar(10), 
No_Of_sibling varchar(10), 
Status varchar(10), 
AddID varchar(10),
QualificationId varchar(10), 
constraint custpk PRIMARY KEY(CustId),
constraint addfk FOREIGN KEY(AddID)
references address(AddID),
constraint qualfk FOREIGN KEY(QualificationId) );
```

Comment: Provide the bare minimum details at least to get the solution on this platform

Comment: You are missing the `references` for `qualfk`.

Comment: I consider it good practice to define each FK constraint as part of the column instead of separately at the end, so that it can inherit the datatype of the referenced column. Also, those `varchar` columns should be `varchar2`. (And while we're at it, are you actually allowed to store a customer's `race`? I think you might be up against [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) at the very least. And what is `AttributeName`?)

Comment: thanks for helping that "attributename" is my mistake i just delete it and for the  race, actually this one for my final project so i need to use all attribute given form my lecutrer. tq

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
CustId varchar(10) not null, 
custname varchar(15), 
Ic varchar(15),
AttributeName varchar(10), 
Birthdate varchar(10), 
Birthstate varchar(10), 
Race varchar(10), 
Gender varchar(10), 
No_Of_sibling varchar(10), 
Status varchar(10), 
AddID varchar(10),
QualificationId varchar(10), 
constraint custpk PRIMARY KEY(CustId),
constraint addfk FOREIGN KEY(AddID)
references address(AddID),
constraint qualfk FOREIGN KEY(QualificationId) REFERENCES **YOUR_PARENT_QUALIFICATION_TABLE_NAME(AND_ITS_COLUMN)**);
```